# What is the dependencies of u-boot in host PC?

Tags: cross-compiling, u-boot

I am trying to cross-compile u-boot on Cygwin. But after installed the arm toolchain, I found still the ton of require libs are missing. For example, flex bison...

I searched these in the readme of u-boot but didn't see such keywords. So Is there any docs about build getting start and host requirements?

Answer (score 1):

On a live Lubuntu system started from [lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso) in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) 6.1.0, required dependencies would be installed by the following command:

```
sudo apt install make gcc bison flex device-tree-compiler python3-distutils swig python3-dev
```

A procedure for building the latest u-boot on a live lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64 system could then be:

```
# Using lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso ISO image

wget "https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/9.2-2019.12/binrel/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz?revision=fed31ee5-2ed7-40c8-9e0e-474299a3c4ac&la=en&hash=76DAF56606E7CB66CC5B5B33D8FB90D9F24C9D20"  -O gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/arm/9
sudo tar Jxf gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz -C /opt/arm/9

wget https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/archive/v2020.01.tar.gz
tar zxf v2020.01.tar.gz

# in the case we would run live fron an ISO image
rm  https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/archive/v2020.01.tar.gz v2020.01.tar.gz

sudo apt install make gcc bison flex device-tree-compiler python3-distutils swig python3-dev

make -C u-boot-2020.01 CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf- mrproper nanopi_m1_defconfig  all

ls -g -G u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1  423674 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1   13103 Jan 10 20:15 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1    8053 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.cfg.configs
-rw-rw-r-- 1   19970 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.dtb
-rw-rw-r-- 1   20113 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.dtb.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1  423738 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.img
-rw-rw-r-- 1    2343 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.lds
-rw-rw-r-- 1  615871 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.map
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1211266 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.srec
-rw-rw-r-- 1  164646 Jan 10 20:16 u-boot-2020.01/u-boot.sym
```

If building on Cygwin is not your ultimate goal, I would strongly suggest to use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) on your Windows PC: you will save a lot of time and will be sure you will be able to build u-boot.

Comment: Hi, I choose Cygwin because I found Cygwin config in u-boot Makefile. So I think Cygwin supposes work... but look like it's not : /